kdb/q Count column-pair instances within a table and return all with particular condition
I have a sales records table that looks like this:



Name
Item
Action
Price




Ann
Apple
Buy
5.00


Ann
Apple
Sell
6.00


Ann
Bread
Sell
9.00


Bob
Apple
Buy
5.00


Bob
Salt
Buy
1.00


Bob
Salt
Buy
1.00


Bob
Salt
Sell
2.00



sample_data: ([] Name: `Ann`Ann`Ann`Bob`Bob`Bob`Bob; Item: `Apple`Apple`Bread`Apple`Salt`Salt`Salt; Action: `Buy`Sell`Sell`Buy`Buy`Buy`Sell; Price: 5.00 6.00 9.00 5.00 1.00 1.00 2.00)

My end result is to get the combination of Names and Items that have been both bought and sold at least once.
My thought process is to create a table like the one below, which collects the number of buys and sells for each Name-Item pair:



Name
Item
Buys
Sells




Ann
Apple
1
1


Ann
Bread
0
1


Bob
Apple
1
0


Bob
Salt
2
1



Then, extract only those Name-Item pairs that have >=1 Buys and Sells:



Name
Item




Ann
Apple


Bob
Salt




An fby might be the simplest way:
q)select distinct Name,Item from sample_data where({all`Buy`Sell in x};Action)fby([]Name;Item)
Name Item
----------
Ann  Apple
Bob  Salt


Thanks for this, I didn't know about fby but it looks very cool. I would give you an upvote but I don't have enough reputation points
